# What is the difference between tf.Tensor( and <tf.Tensor: >

Tags: python, tensorflow, variables, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

Consider below code

```
import pprint

import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
ratings = tfds.load("movielens/100k-ratings", split="train")
movies = tfds.load("movielens/100k-movies", split="train")

ratings = ratings.map(lambda x: {
    "movie_title": x["movie_title"],
    "user_id": x["user_id"],
    "user_rating": x["user_rating"],
    # "timestamp": x["timestamp"],
})
movies = movies.map(lambda x: x["movie_title"])
type(movies)
for example in movies.take(2):
  # pprint.pprint(tf.reshape(example['movie_title'],[3,5,1]))
  pprint.pprint(example)
```

The above code will give me output as below

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=string, numpy=b'You So Crazy (1994)'>
<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=string, numpy=b'Love Is All There Is (1996)'>
```

Now below code will give different result.

Lets say we have below data in a csv file with name `songs_details.csv`

```
,song_id,title,release,artist_name,year,count
0,SOAAAGQ12A8C1420C8,Orgelblut,Dolores,Bohren  Der Club Of Gore,2008,1
1,SOAACPJ12A81C21360,Cearc Agus Coileach  The Hen And Cock,CasadhTurning,Mchel  Silleabhin,1,1
2,SOAAEJI12AB0188AB5,Godlovesugly,God Loves Ugly,Atmosphere,1,1
3,SOAAFAC12A67ADF7EB,Rome Wasnt Built In A Day,Parts Of The Process,Morcheeba,2000,2
4,SOAAKPM12A58A77210,So Confused feat Butta Creame amended album version,Late Night Special,Pretty Ricky,2007,1
5,SOAAOYI12AB01831CE,Criminal,Gotan Project live,Gotan Project,2006,2
```

Now lets read this csv file and process it

```
songs = tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset(
    "./songs_details.csv",
    batch_size=128,
    select_columns=['song_id','title','release','artist_name','year'],
    num_epochs=1,
    ignore_errors=True,)
songs = songs.unbatch().map(lambda x: {
    "song_id":x["song_id"],
    "release":x["release"],
    "artist_name":x["artist_name"],
    "title":x["title"],
    "year":x["year"],
})

for example in songs.map(lambda x: x['title']).take(2):
  print(example)
```

The above will produce output as below

```
tf.Tensor(b'Skip The Youth', shape=(), dtype=string)
tf.Tensor(b'Teenage Dirtbag', shape=(), dtype=string)
```

are there any difference between the two representation of variables, I mean between `tf.Tensor()` and `<tf.Tensor: >`

TF version used is 2.9.1

Comment: Try using `pprint.pprint` in the 2nd example - does it still show different output?

Comment: @Stuart see answer below.

Comment: @AloneTogether `pprint` should not diverge from ordinary `print` in this way, so I'm trying to understand if that is really happening and why

Comment: It is happening. Using `pprint` for both cases will yield the same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no significant differences between the two representations of the variables. The only difference is that you use `pprint` for one variable and `print` for the other variable. Both functions seem to print Tensorflow tensors a little differently. However, this does not affect the tensors themselves. Printing both with `pprint` or `print` will yield the same results.